# Node red with lamp stack?

Tags: lamp, node-red

i've installed a xamp stack onto a raspberry pi and it is collecting data from 5 arduino sensors. My question is can i also install node-red into my raspberry pi to help me with creating the IoT dashboard for the client side?

Will there be any collision or interference between my lamp stack and nodered?

I am using raspbian buster lite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no interaction between the a LAMP stack and Node-RED out of the box.

Comment: so it should be fine if i install nodered onto my raspberry pi?